# Writing a unix or perl script to check if a process is running

Tags: perl, unix, process

I have 4 app servers. I want to check that all 4 are up and running so I want to write a script that I check for the process on all app servers (without me having to log onto each one and run the script). The app servers have a share folder which they all have access to so I can place the script there.
I want to find out the easiest/most efficient way to check this on all 4 app servers. The original plan was to ssh to each of the servers but this then asks you for your password and other prompts which will cause issues. I was looking into using keygen, but I don't have a home dir on the servers and I was having issues generating keys. 
I wanted to know if anyone could suggest the best way to do this via a script. Which would be better/more efficient, perl or unix? Are there other options of doing this that I am missing other than keygen?
Any advise will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with the ssh approach?

Comment: I don't want to set the password in the script and I've been told that passing it in as a parameter would not work (as it prompts you for other things, such as saying yes), but keygen is meant to allow me to do this without a password. I can't get this set up as I don't have a home profile on the box (getting one soon but not there yet). I'm just looking for some opinions/ideas on if this is the best approach or if there is a better way of doing this out there.

Comment: you might want to look into expect. It makes responding to prompts very easy. Without ssh-keys though, you will still need to have the password in the script, which is not great.

Comment: For automated monitoring and recovery I really like monit.  It may or may not fit your needs here, but consider it either as a daemon running on all your target hosts OR as the driver for your monitoring scripts on a single monitoring host.  http://mmonit.com/monit/

Comment: If you can add functionality to your app servers it might be easier to embed a webserver (or other tcp server) so you can probe them without needing to be on the target system.  Or ember a heartbeat generator, so they report their status without being asked.  If all you have is binaries, this obviously isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar using Perl. If you use Net:SSH:Expect, you can open a connection with a password into each machine, run your commands, check output and repeat.

Here's what'll get you started.
[CPAN - Net:SSH:Expect](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%253A%253ASSH%253A%253AExpect&rct=j&q=NET%3aSSH%3aEXpect&ei=UiwTTsWaDMySgQfFvZT5DQ&usg=AFQjCNGnNfxuPrwQ9WjjCpuTc_aKKTGjZw&cad=rja)

Sample code to get inside of desired machine:

```
    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
        host     => $sshHost,
        password => 'password',
        user     => 'username',
        raw_pty  => 1
    );

my $login_output = $ssh->login(); # check if you logged in properly

# disable terminal translations and echo on the SSH server
$ssh->exec("stty raw -echo");
```

You can call exec to run whatever commands you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a cron job on each server that does the checking, and when the process isn't there, sends a message - could be an HTTP request, an e-mail, whatever you fancy.

Comment: I thought about using cron jobs, but I found out that I can't use cron jobs for this.

Answer (score 0):

without being able to setup ssh key's or a cron entry; my guess is rsh is out also.  Off the top of my head; that leaves expect... http://search.cpan.org/~bnegrao/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get a script running, something like this would work.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then echo "Usage $0: <hispidfile>" >&2; exit 1; fi
read otherpid < $1
if [ "$otherpid" -lt 1 ]; then
  otherpid=""
fi
while :; do
 while kill -0 $otherpid
  do
   sleep 1
  done
 # restart other program
 # (really restarting myself in my peer configuration)
 echo restarting him
 sh -c 'echo $$ > '$1'; echo Him is running for 5 seconds PID=`cat '$1'`; sleep 5;' &
 newpid=0
 while [ "$newpid" -eq "$otherpid" -o "$newpid" -lt 1 ]
  do
   sleep 2
   read newpid < $1
  done
 otherpid=$newpid
done
```